# Make Column A equal to Column B in height

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, multiple-columns

I'm trying to get 2 columns on a web page to be the same height. The height of the column's not set in advanced. What I want to accomplish is that Column A is always equal to column B. In case column A has more content it has to get a scroll bar.

I do have the 2 columns in a parent container but either column A is smaller or column A stretches the parent container. The height for column A is decided by column B. The project does use bootstrap.

```
<div class="parent col-md-12">
  <div class="colA col-md-3"></div>
  <div class="colB col-md-9"></div>
</div>
```

Desired outcome:

- if column A is 50px and B 100px, make A 100px
- If column A is 100px and B 100px, make A 100px (no change needed)
- If column A is 150px and B 100px, make A 100px

Comment: Can you append some code so as to have a clear understanding of the question.

Comment: @AakashThakur add*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With a minor change in the HTML this is possible with Flexbox.

Columnb will take the height of ColumnB but the content of ColumnA in inside an absolutely positioned div with 100% height (and overflow).

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.colA {
  position: relative;
  background: pink;
  flex: 1;
}
.colB {
  height: 75px;
  flex: 1;
  background: lightblue;
}
.inner {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}
.tall .colB {
  height: 180px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="colA">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium accusantium iure nostrum nemo eaque sunt impedit reiciendis expedita ducimus necessitatibus voluptas excepturi, deleniti aut repellat! Porro nihil nemo, ipsum ipsa reiciendis quis
        cupiditate fugiat quam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colB"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent tall">
  <div class="colA">
    <div class="inner">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laudantium accusantium iure nostrum nemo eaque sunt impedit reiciendis expedita ducimus necessitatibus voluptas excepturi, deleniti aut repellat! Porro nihil nemo, ipsum ipsa reiciendis quis
        cupiditate fugiat quam!</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="colB"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: gave it a little test, it does seem promising so far.

Comment: it works for the height problem, unfortunately it overrules bootstrap colums into 2 colums of 50%. i forgot to mention that i am using bootstrap columns for a 3-9 column widths.

Comment: You can still use bootstrap columns, just remove the `flex:1` it shoudl still work. - http://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/jraEJN

Comment: i got it to work, with bootstrap column alignment etc so thanks for that, now i only have a scrollbar that moves it self over into the over column but that shouldn't be that difficult to fix. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you want there to be a scrollbar, I can't think of a wait that this can be achieved without JS.

```js
function resize(){
$('#col-2').height($('#col-1').height());
}

$(function(){
resize();
});
```

```css
*{
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.column{
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  padding: 1.25rem;
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column" id="col-1">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vehicula, enim non sollicitudin molestie, dolor
        diam auctor turpis, eget venenatis ligula eros nec mi. Quisque bibendum erat a magna pretium finibus.
        Suspendisse vehicula lectus felis, quis pharetra purus commodo et. Praesent nec suscipit elit. Vivamus vitae mi
        libero. Curabitur malesuada blandit velit, eget venenatis nisi malesuada ut. Praesent sollicitudin lacus quis
        elit placerat, dapibus luctus purus facilisis. Integer eget congue libero, nec euismod mauris. Duis aliquet odio
        nulla, lacinia vulputate orci tincidunt quis. Quisque magna sapien, tincidunt a suscipit sed, imperdiet non
        tellus. Mauris sagittis neque sed suscipit molestie. Suspendisse ultricies sollicitudin tortor quis maximus.
        Suspendisse condimentum facilisis sagittis. Duis quis malesuada nisi, non euismod augue. Phasellus rutrum, nunc
        ac dictum facilisis, ipsum turpis suscipit metus, id sagittis eros mauris in mi. Fusce odio purus, dignissim id
        erat eu, pellentesque vehicula nisi.
    </div>
    <div class="column" id="col-2">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vehicula, enim non sollicitudin molestie, dolor
        diam auctor turpis, eget venenatis ligula eros nec mi. Quisque bibendum erat a magna pretium finibus.
        Suspendisse vehicula lectus felis, quis pharetra purus commodo et. Praesent nec suscipit elit. Vivamus vitae mi
        libero. Curabitur malesuada blandit velit, eget venenatis nisi malesuada ut. Praesent sollicitudin lacus quis
        elit placerat, dapibus luctus purus facilisis. Integer eget congue libero, nec euismod mauris. Duis aliquet odio
        nulla, lacinia vulputate orci tincidunt quis. Quisque magna sapien, tincidunt a suscipit sed, imperdiet non
        tellus. Mauris sagittis neque sed suscipit molestie. Suspendisse ultricies sollicitudin tortor quis maximus.
        Suspendisse condimentum facilisis sagittis. Duis quis malesuada nisi, non euismod augue. Phasellus rutrum, nunc
        ac dictum facilisis, ipsum turpis suscipit metus, id sagittis eros mauris in mi. Fusce odio purus, dignissim id
        erat eu, pellentesque vehicula nisi.

        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam vehicula, enim non sollicitudin molestie, dolor
        diam auctor turpis, eget venenatis ligula eros nec mi. Quisque bibendum erat a magna pretium finibus.
        Suspendisse vehicula lectus felis, quis pharetra purus commodo et. Praesent nec suscipit elit. Vivamus vitae mi
        libero. Curabitur malesuada blandit velit, eget venenatis nisi malesuada ut. Praesent sollicitudin lacus quis
        elit placerat, dapibus luctus purus facilisis. Integer eget congue libero, nec euismod mauris. Duis aliquet odio
        nulla, lacinia vulputate orci tincidunt quis. Quisque magna sapien, tincidunt a suscipit sed, imperdiet non
        tellus. Mauris sagittis neque sed suscipit molestie. Suspendisse ultricies sollicitudin tortor quis maximus.
        Suspendisse condimentum facilisis sagittis. Duis quis malesuada nisi, non euismod augue. Phasellus rutrum, nunc
        ac dictum facilisis, ipsum turpis suscipit metus, id sagittis eros mauris in mi. Fusce odio purus, dignissim id
        erat eu, pellentesque vehicula nisi.
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use javaScript as the height isn't predetermined

```js
var colA = $('.col-a'),
    colB = $('.col-b'),
    AHeight = $('.col-a').height(),
    BHeight = $('.col-b').height();

if ( BHeight > AHeight ) {
  colA.height(BHeight);
} else {
  colA.height(BHeight).addClass('scroll');
}
```

```css
.parent {
  overflow: hidden; 
}
.parent [class^="col"] {
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.parent [class^="col"]:nth-child(even) {
  background: #ccc;
}
.parent [class^="col"]:nth-child(odd) {
  background: #eee;
}

.scroll {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
  <div class="col-a">
  <stong>Column A</stong>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lacinia a scelerisque lectus ut, magna semper curabitur neque luctus et sodales, porttitor sollicitudin laoreet donec nam mattis, placerat fusce justo, in at tempor. In et, sem et ac in. Blandit aenean, pellentesque rutrum lacinia volutpat morbi mollis nulla. Interdum in neque duis vivamus, lacus non at, vel consectetuer vitae metus. Molestie vehicula vestibulum dui suscipit, arcu et aliquam ullamcorper.
</p>
  </div>
  <div class="col-b">
  <stong>Column B</stong>
    <p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, lacinia a scelerisque lectus ut, magna semper curabitur neque luctus et sodales, porttitor sollicitudin laoreet donec nam mattis.
</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

.

Comment: Unfortunately this makes it so the shorter one gets stretched to match the longest. What i need is that column A gets set to the same size as colum B

Answer (score -1):

You can use "display:flex" for equal width/height of columns.

Here is the link for full description of "display:flex" :-

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: How would you make the least tall column the leading column for height with flex?

Comment: Sorry it's my fault, i left the scrolling part. 
according to the question both boxes are need same height in all three condition. this condition fulfill by "display:flex".
and for scrolling part you need to use some jquery and html modification.
html :-
<div class="parent">
  <div class="colA"><div class="colA-in"></div></div>
  <div class="colB"><div class="colA-in"></div></div>
</div>
You need to apply display flex on colA and colB and after that you use colA-in and colB-in for get different height of content. and you can add scroll according to that.